# About two 'negative' continued fractions whose sum equals $1$

Tags: number-theory, fractions

Letting $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_r$ be integers which are larger than or equal to $2$, let us define 
$$[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_r]=\frac{1}{a_1-\frac{1}{a_2-\frac{1}{\ddots-\frac{1}{a_r}}}}$$

(Note that the **negative signs** are used)

Also, let $X, Y, Z$ be positive integers which satisfy
$$Z\lt X+Y,\  Z\gt X,\  Z\gt Y$$
and let 
$$\frac XZ=[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_r],\ \frac YZ=[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_s].$$

Then, here is my question.

**Question** : Is the following true?

"There exist $r^{\prime}\le r, s^{\prime}\le s$ such that 
$$[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{r^{\prime}}]+[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_{s^{\prime}}]=1$$
for any $(X,Y,Z)$."

**Remark** : Observing the initial numbers is not sufficient because the nearer to $1$ the value $\frac XZ+\frac YZ$ is, the harder it is to find the answer (see example 2).

**Examples** :

1. $\frac XZ=\frac 37=[3,2,2]$ and $\frac YZ=\frac 57=[2,2,3]$ leads $[3]+[2,2]=\frac 13+\frac 23=1$ where $\frac 37+\frac 57=\frac 87\approx 1.143$
2. $\frac XZ=\frac{901}{2067}=[3,2,2,4,2]$ and $\frac YZ=\frac{1170}{2067}=[2,5,2,2,3]$ leads $[3,2,2,4]+[2,5,2,2]=\frac{10}{23}+\frac{13}{23}=1$ where $\frac XZ+\frac YZ=\frac{2071}{2067}\approx 1.002.$

**Motivation** : I've got an algorithm to find $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_s$ such that 
$$1-x=[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_s]$$
for any given $x=[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_r]$.

**Algorithm** : Supposing that $2^r$ represents $r$-consective $2$s, I'm going to write 
$$[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_r]=[2^{q_1},p_1,2^{q_2},p_2,\cdots,2^{q_s},p_s,2^{q_{s+1}}]$$
where $p_i\ge 3\in \mathbb N, q_i\ge 0\in \mathbb Z$. For example, $[2,2,5,3,2,4]=[2^2,5,2^0,3,2^1,4,2^0]$.

Then, the algorithm is 
$$1-[2^{q_1},p_1,2^{q_2},p_2,\cdots,2^{q_s},p_s,2^{q_{s+1}}]$$
$$=[(q_1+2),2^{(p_1-3)},(q_2+3),2^{(p_2-3)},(q_3+3),2^{(p_3-3)},\cdots,(q_s+3),2^{(p_s-3)},(q_{s+1}+2)].$$

After getting this algorithm, I reached the above expectation. I can neither find any counterexample even by using computer nor prove that the expectation is true. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144996/about-two-negative-continued-fractions-whose-sum-equals-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Alexey Ustinov on MO.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144996/about-two-negative-continued-fractions-whose-sum-equals-1